# WPF binding navigation property to combobox

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Context: I am using EF 5 and trying to bind two entities to a WPF form. It works fine with simples property-to-textbox binding, but I'd like to bind a navigation property object to a combobox. I am learning WPF so this may be obvious.

I have two EF entities:

```
Product { int Id, string Name, Category Category }
```

and

```
Category { int Id, string Description }
```

I made a WPF form to create and edit products, it is something like this (simplified):

```
        <Window.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="productViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:product, CreateList=True}" />
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="categoryViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:category, CreateList=True}" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource productViewSource}">
            <Label Content="Id" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,8,0,0" Name="txtId" Text="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" IsEnabled="False" />
            <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,38,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,40,0,0" Name="txtNome" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" IsEnabled="False" />

            <Label Content="Category" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,129,0,0" Name="label5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,132,0,0" Name="comboCategory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                      SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Category, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=categoryViewSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
            </ComboBox>
         </Grid>
```

The code to load the two View Sources is this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        context = new DBEntities();

        var productViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("productViewSource")));
        context.Product.Include(p => p.Category);
        context.Product.Load();
        ProductViewSource.Source = context.Product.Local;

        var categoryViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("categoryViewSource")));
        categoryViewSource.Source = context.Category.ToList();
    }
```

When the window loads the two textboxes work, but the combobox is always empty.

Probally this is what is wrong, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=categoryViewSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

`ItemsSource="{Binding Path=categoryViewSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">`

What you're telling WPF here is that you want the **Property** `categoryViewSource` from the first `Window` it encounters upwards in the Visual Tree. Of course the `Window` Class doesn't have such property.

It should be:

`ItemsSource="{StaticResource categoryViewSource}">`

which tells WPF you want to look up a **Resource** with that name (key)

**Edit:** You'd better create a ViewModel to hold your data:

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public List<Category> Categories {get;set;} //Don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged!!

     //... other properties
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    context = new DBEntities();

    var vm = new ViewModel() { Categories = context.Category.ToList(); }

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"/>
```

Remove the Static Resources and remove all references to them.

**Edit 2:**

The `SelectedValuePath` And `SelectedValue` Properties work together. The `SelectedValuePath` is telling the ComboBox "Evaluate this property inside each item", and the `SelectedValue` property is the actual value you expect to find in that property, so:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Category}"/>
```

Is telling WPF that you have some **`int`** property called `Category` in your DataContext class which you expect to contain a value matching the **`Id`** of one of your entities.

What you actually need to do here is:

**ViewModel:**

```
public Category Category {get;set;} //Don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged!!!
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Category}"/>
```

and remove both SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue.

Comment: this specific way to declare gives an error that StaticResource expects an IEnumerable but it is a CollectionViewSource

Comment: @Pedro That's another problem in itself. I don't see why you are using the CollectionViewSource stuff. You'd better create a ViewModel to hold the data you get from the DB and bind your elements directly to that.

Comment: right. I was following this MS tutorial, but it stopped after the basics. So I'll try from scratch.

Comment: still, do you know a resource that address this specific case? (trying to bind a property to a combobox?)

Comment: @Pedro see my Edit. I suggest you take a look at MVVM.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it. Can you please also take a look at the SelectedValue part? Is something wrong?

Comment: In the end it worked and I learned a lot, thank you for your patience.